# How can I detect a discontinuity on railways?

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I have a project at school that asks me to detect any discontinuity on railways. The idea is taking a video of railways (it's a model, the witdh of the railways is only 3 cm) thanks to a camera, and then a program (I have to create) has to be able to detect any discontinuity on the railways.

For now, I created a program able to detect horizontal lines (it can be changed easily to detect vertical lines if necessary, depending on how the video is taken). My idea is to calculate the distance between two lines in order to detect a discontinuity if the distance is too high. The problem is, my program has some difficulties to detect long lines (it detects a lot of little lines instead).

Does anyone has an idea to detect all the railways with only 2 big lines instead of a lot of little lines ?
I tried to look on internet to find something helpful, but this program is the only one I found. Maybe someone already has something to detect railways ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Here is the code I work on :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math as m

camera = cv2.VideoCapture('mavideo.mp4')

while (camera.isOpened()):
    ret,frame1 = camera.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame1,(600,600)) 

    edge = cv2.Canny(frame,100,200,apertureSize=3)

    minLineLength = 10
    maxLineGap = 15

    line = cv2.HoughLinesP(edge,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)


    if line is not None:

            for (x1,y1,x2,y2) in line[0]:
                if y2==y1:
                    cv2.line(frame,(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0,255,0),5)

                    if line.any()==True:
                        d = m.sqrt(m.pow((x2-x1),2)+m.pow((y2-y1),2))
                        print d
                        print "Line Detected"

            cv2.imshow("line detection",frame)
            cv2.imshow('edge',edge)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
               break
    else:
        print "Line not detected"
        #'http://192.168.43.1:8080/'      


camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[First example of the results of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KsWv.png)

[Second example of the results of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOxAo.png)

Comment: Try to create bounding boxes instead of detection lines. Then if you have more than one box then you probably have discontinuity, otherwise (you have one box) you need to check border of box for collision with border of frame.

Comment: All right I'm gonna try this. Thank you for your answer !